# Is there a difference with Task.Run a void method and Task method returning null?

Tags: c#, task

Consider a form with 2 buttons and a richtextbox:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts;
    CancellationToken token;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        token = cts.Token;
        var task = Task.Run(() => WriteSomeLines(), token);
    }

    private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        cts.Dispose();
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        token = cts.Token;
        var task = Task.Run(() => WriteSomeLines(), token);
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            cts.Cancel();
            cts.Dispose();
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.GetType().Name);
            //object disposed
        }
    }

    public void WriteSomeLines()
    {
        if (ControlInvokeRequired(rtbLoops, () => rtbLoops.Text += "Starting new loop \r\n")) ;
        else rtbLoops.Text += "Starting new loop \r\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ControlInvokeRequired(rtbLoops, () => { rtbLoops.AppendText("New line " + i + "\r\n"); rtbLoops.ScrollToCaret(); })) ;
                else rtbLoops.AppendText("New line " + i + "\r\n");

                Thread.Sleep(250);
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException ae)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ae.GetType().Name);
                return;
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    public bool ControlInvokeRequired(Control c, Action a)
    {
        if (c.InvokeRequired)
            c.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { a(); }));
        else
            return false;

        return true;
    }      
}
```

Is there a difference if     `WriteSomeLines()` is returning void and I use return inside, or if `WriteSomeLines()` returns Task and I do return null there? I read that I cannot use `await` with void returning methods, but inserting

```
await task;
```

after task declaration (in the code above) compiles perfectly fine, and runs with no issues.

Edit:

```
private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        token = cts.Token;
        var task = Task.Run(() => WriteSomeLines(), token);
        await task;
        rtbLoops.Text += "Task complete";
    }
```

This compiles with no issues if `WriteSomeLines()` returns void.

Also, slightly unrealted, am I disposing `CancellationTokenSource` correctly here?

Second Edit:

So is this the correct approach:

```
 private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cts.Dispose();
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        token = cts.Token;
        var task = Task.Run(() => WriteSomeLines(), token);
        bool result = await task;
        if(result == true) rtbLoops.Text += "Task complete \r\n";
    }
```

and

```
public async Task<bool> WriteSomeLines()
    {
        if (ControlInvokeRequired(rtbLoops, () => rtbLoops.Text += "Starting new loop \r\n")) ;
        else rtbLoops.Text += "Starting new loop \r\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ControlInvokeRequired(rtbLoops, () => { rtbLoops.AppendText("New line " + i + "\r\n"); rtbLoops.ScrollToCaret(); })) ;
                else rtbLoops.AppendText("New line " + i + "\r\n");
                await Task.Delay(250);
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException ae)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ae.GetType().Name);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never return a null task; that should cause a runtime `NullReferenceException` error.

You can use `await` *within* an `async void` method, but you cannot use `await` to *consume* an `async void` method (because you cannot `await` `void`).

I recommend that you review my [`async` intro blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html); it should help you get a better understanding of `async` and `await`.

> am I disposing CancellationTokenSource correctly here?

Your start button needs to cancel/dispose the old `cts` when it creates a new one.